# Writing Unit Test Cases for Preact

Tags: jestjs, enzyme, preact

I am very new to Preact and I have to write unit test cases for an application in Preact. I can find that jest and enzyme can be used for the same but I run into errors every time. Can anyone suggest some blog or tutorial on how to write unit test cases on Preact?

Comment: What errors gave you? I'm investigating on using enzyme now that the version 3 has been released and could be used for testing more frameworks and not just only React. FWIW, this issue in preact's github has a few options: https://github.com/developit/preact/issues/658

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

Now is [preact-enzyme-adapter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/enzyme-adapter-preact) available which makes it possible to run preact testing with [Enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme). I haven't tested it yet, but I'd recommend it a try since Enzyme got a really nice toolbelt and already is widely used.

**Original answer**

[This preact boilerplate project](https://github.com/developit/preact-boilerplate) has a setup with unit tests included. They're using `jest` to run the tests.

Below is, as a I understand, the relevant parts to get up and running.

package.json

```
  "jest": {
    "setupFiles": [
      "./test/setup.js"
    ],
    "testURL": "http://localhost:8080",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
      "^react$": "preact-compat",
      "^react-dom$": "preact-compat"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}"
    ]
  },
```

test/setup.js:

```
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';
import chai from 'chai';
import assertJsx, { options } from 'preact-jsx-chai';

// when checking VDOM assertions, don't compare functions, just nodes and attributes:
options.functions = false;

// activate the JSX assertion extension:
chai.use(assertJsx);

global.sleep = ms => new Promise( resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms) );
```

home/index.test.js

```
import { h } from 'preact';
import { expect } from 'chai';

import Home from '../../../src/components/home';

describe('components/home', () => {
    it('should show the home text', () => {
        const home = <Home/>;
        expect(home).to.contain(<h1>Home</h1>);
        expect(home).to.contain('Home component');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this template project](https://github.com/yaitskov/preact-render-spy-with-typescript-setup) with preact-render-spy and it doesn't have dependencies on react nor enzyme. As plus TypeScript is also configured.